# Render Not working - coming out black - Nothing in render window

Tags: rendering, animation, video

I am rendering a video of coins falling into a box. I rendered yesterday with no issues but today it is not working.

The render completes way too fast and the render window remains blank. The video then comes out completely black. Lights etc are all fine, rendered as an image to check and all good.

Anyone have any idea what the issues is? I tried all the answers I found but no luck.

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have any strip in your Video Sequencer? In that case deactivate the Output > Post-Processing > Sequencer

Comment: No there doesn't appear to be anything in Video Sequencer.

Comment: You should attach your blend file to the post.

Comment: Added file now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bake the physics. Press <kbd>F3</kbd> and search `bake all physics`.

[image]

With physics baked, you should have no problems

Comment: Rockstar! It's exporting now, although it looks like it will take a few hours to complete...

Comment: @Diarmuid if the answer is correct, mark it as such  ;)